# Content-Length http header stripped out on Sprint 3G network

Tags: iphone, ios, wcf, iis, 3g

I have a server I am communicating with and I get a Content-Length header in the response when I connect with my iPhone 4S via WiFi, or via Web Browser. If I disable WiFi and use my Sprint 3G connection on my iPhone 4S, the Content-Length header in the response is missing.

Server is running WCF under IIS 7.5 ...

Does anyone know why this might happen?

Comment: I am also seeing this. Did you ever figure out why this was happening or a way to work around it?

Comment: The problem is Sprint as it doesn't happen on other networks or WiFi. To work around, we show a generic spinner in cases where the content length header is missing.